# shell script to reset Evolution passwords

Tags: ubuntu

I posted the following question to the Ubuntu forum and no success yet.  I realize this is less of a programming issue and more of an Evolution/Ubuntu issue, but given that I want to automate the solution it seems not inappropriate to post it here...

Here is the problem. I changed my Google account password recently and now Evolution (Ubuntu mail client) can no longer connect to the Google address book... and it appears there is no way to reset it through the Evolution GUI.  Deleting and re-adding the address book does not work, nor does unchecking the 'remember password' checkboxes in both send/receive tabs for my Google mail account reset the Google address book password (which was a long shot and doesn't really make sense anyway).

I'd like to write a script -- albeit a specialized one -- that fixes this problem in Evolution when a user changes their google password.  Any ideas about how this script would work?

Answer (score 3):

evolution keeps it's passwords in gnome-keyring

Applications > Accessories > Passwords and Encryption Keys

From here, goto the passwords tab, find the correct password entry, double click on it, expand the password section, then click "show password" and change your password here.